# How to create in memory data structure list in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, in-memory

I am new to plsql programming. I want to create a list of in-memory data-structure which holds list of records like this

```
name, city, phone
john, New York, +1-88686
john, London, +44-5343
john, Hong Kong, +33-6556565
```

I want to do something like  this

```
create table EmployeeTab(
 name varchar2(20),
 city varchar2(20),
 phone varchar(20)
);
```

But, I could not find the correct syntax. I am using Oracle 11g.

Comment: So do you want that in-memory list available to just the current user of your PL/SQL package, or for many users?  How long does the data need to be around?  Are you wanting it to be "in memory" for performance?  If the size of the table is small, you can just create a normal table, but add the clause `STORAGE( BUFFER_POOL KEEP)` which could increase the chances of it being cached.

Comment: I want the in-memory list for just one user in pl/sql. I want to keep this around only till the program is executing and want it to be removed once the program finishes. This is essentially a list of an in-memory data structure which I want to maintain. Something like a Collection< EmployeeTab> as in Java or other languages.

Comment: please edit your post and add your comment

Answer (score 1):

If you want you can use a TYPE RECORD.
Example:

```
    type EmployeeTab is record 
          (name varchar(20), 
           city varchar(20), 
           phone varchar(20));
 v_EmployeeTab EmployeeTab;
```

Then you can save yuor data in this way:

```
   v_EmployeeTab.name  := '...'; 
   v_EmployeeTab.city  := '...';  
   v_EmployeeTab.phone := '...';
```

I suggest you to visit:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_records.htm

Comment: For creating one record its fine. But, I want to create a collection of this EmployeeTab record. Can this be achieved?

Comment: YES, I think there are different ways.

If you know the number of collections you can create many objects of type EmployeeTab, otherwise, it may be a good idea to use temporary tables to save data, you can visit: https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefdeclaretemptable.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use Index by table

If you want in memory data structure for a particular table then you define like below

```
TYPE <typename> IS TABLE OF <tablename>%rowtype INDEX BY binary_integer;
<variablename> <typename>; -- declare variable for that type
```

If you want index by table for your record then you can use recordname%rowtype
if you want index by table for your cursor then you can use cursorname%rowtype

Index by table will be useful to pass set of values to another procedure